# Bigtable bulkload using Dataflow is too slow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-bigtable

What is the best way to do bulk load to Bigtable for patterns like 20GB data files every 3 hrs? Is Dataflow right way for this?

Our issue with bulk loading Bigtable using Dataflow is..

Looks like Dataflow QPS is not matching QPS of Bigtable (of 5 nodes). I am trying to load 20GB file(s) to bigtable using Dataflow. It is taking 4 hrs to ingest into bigtable. Also I keep getting this warning during the run..

```
{
  "code" : 429,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Request throttled due to project QPS limit being reached.",
    "reason" : "rateLimitExceeded"
  } ],
  "message" : "Request throttled due to project QPS limit being reached.",
  "status" : "RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED"
}.
```

Code:

```java
// CloudBigtableOptions is one way to retrieve the options. It's not
// required.
CloudBigtableOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(btargs.toArray(new String[btargs.size()]))
    .withValidation().as(CloudBigtableOptions.class);

// CloudBigtableTableConfiguration contains the project, zone, cluster
// and table to connect to.
CloudBigtableTableConfiguration config = CloudBigtableTableConfiguration.fromCBTOptions(options);

Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

// This sets up serialization for Puts and Deletes so that Dataflow can
// potentially move them through the network.
CloudBigtableIO.initializeForWrite(p);

p.apply(TextIO.Read.from(inpath)).apply(ParDo.of(new CreatePutsFn(columns, delim)))
    .apply(CloudBigtableIO.writeToTable(config));

p.run();
```

CreatePutsFn:

```java
@Override
public void processElement(DoFn<String, Mutation>.ProcessContext c) throws Exception {
    String[] vals = c.element().split(this.delim);
    for (int i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
        if (i != keyPos && vals[i].trim() != "") {
            c.output(new Put(vals[keyPos].getBytes()).addColumn(FAMILY, Bytes.toBytes(columns[i].toLowerCase()),
                    Bytes.toBytes(vals[i])));
        }
    }
}
```

Any help here is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I properly tagged some code you had lying around and was unreadable. Always put code inside the code tags so it can be properly formatted.

Comment: Thanks Andres for tagging properly

Comment: I think it's the other way around - your saturating the Bigtable cluster.  You can temporarily increase your Bigtable cluster size during the import, then reduce the size when done. (to save money) The number of nodes is very dynamic.

Comment: If that doesn't fix it, how many Dataflow nodes / of what size do you have writing?

Comment: Next possibility - how long have you had your account / projectID?  You may be running into a different limit -- Take a look at: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/resource-quotas  -- You may wish increase some quota.

Comment: @LesVogel-GoogleDevRel I tried to boost the bigtable to 15 nodes from 3.. but still the performance is same. Also number of worker nodes are boosted to 40 from 20.. the improvement is very little so i presume it is related to Dataflow QPS. Not sure though

Comment: Have you contacted support yet?  They should be able to lift the limits for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could able to resolve this issue. I did the following three things to get to the desired result. Now this job runs and ingest the data in around 15 mins for a (20 Gb) file(s).. which was previously running for 4-5 hours.

1. This Job creates 2 Billion put requests in 3 mins using Data-flow which are now reduced to 40 million requests by batching all columns for a row.

```java
    public void processElement(DoFn<String, Mutation>.ProcessContext c) throws Exception {
        String[] vals = c.element().split(this.delim);
        Put put = new Put(vals[keyPos].getBytes());
        for (int i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
            if (i != keyPos && vals[i].trim() != "") {
                put.addColumn(FAMILY, Bytes.toBytes(columns[i].toLowerCase()), Bytes.toBytes(vals[i]));

            }
        }
        c.output(put);
    }
```

2. I added the property for client write buffer 
   `config.toHBaseConfig().set("hbase.client.write.buffer", "200971520”);`
3. You were right about bigtable reaching limit on QPS. So during bulk load operation I temporarily boosted the cluster size to 10 nodes (from 3).

Comment: You might wish to look into using a BufferedMutator as well.

Comment: @LesVogel-GoogleDevRel isn't CloudBigtableIO.writeToTable(config) internally doing BufferedMutation thru CloudBigtableSingleTableWriteFn??

Comment: You are correct - what you are doing should be enough.

Comment: @PraveenK — sounds like you’ve solved your issue! Can you please [accept your own answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/) so that this question is marked as closed? Thanks!